# Should I store the avatar of each user on the server?

Tags: php, html, algorithm, performance

I have a website like SO. I mean when user creates an account, my website creates an avatar for him *(based on his IP and name)*. The image is created by PHP. The size of that image *(in the expected width/height)* is 10kb.

**My question:** Should I store the avatar of each user on the server? Or should I create it every time by PHP and no need to store it?

---

Actually I'm worry about the space. To store such images *(for 2 million users)* I have to devote `20` gb of the server's space:

```
2,000,000 * 10 kb = 20,000,000 kb = 20 gb
```

Well it doesn't seem reasonable to me. Am I right? If yes, so what should I do?

Comment: I guess that when you reach 2 millions users, you don't care about spending $10 to 100 a year for 20gb.

Comment: @IvanGabriele So do you mean I have to store those avatars?

Comment: Beside the joke, I gave you a real answer ;)

Comment: If you have 2M users, you likely will need a bigger plan from your host-provider, to handle all the traffic and processing needed - so the 20GB will likely be included from such plans anyway.

Comment: @Qirel Ok find .. just I don't know why all people focus on *2M users* `:-)` .. Actually my question is about either "storing" or "generating" user's avatar, Not the number of users.

Comment: Because in your example, you asked for 2M users. If you're asking which principle is better, storing is in nearly every case better. In this case, it is better. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a real answer, between using processor resources and data storage, you almost always choose data storage because :

- Processing resources are generally more expensive than data storage,
- Processing more means a slower server response time, which is generally a high priority to get your users (and your SEO) happy.

Comment: You are right .. thank you, upvote

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 million users, 20 gig of server space should be the least of your worries. Calculate with realistic numbers first.

Comment: Actually I'm a realistic person + being a few futuristic `;-)`